# Event notifications in macOS

Tags: macos, timemachine

Is it possible for a macOS application to listen for specific events originating from another application?

I'd like to detect when Time Machine backups are initiated, in order to create point-in-time snapshots of the NAS folder where the sparsebundle is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Time Machine engine sends *distributed notifications*.

Add an observer

**Objective-C**

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                   selector:@selector(handleNotifications:)
                                                       name:nil
                                                     object:nil];
```

**Swift**

```
DistributedNotificationCenter.default().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleNotifications), name: nil, object: nil)
```

and implement the corresponding selector

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)handleNotifications:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"%@", notification);
}
```

**Swift**

```
@objc func handleNotifications(_ notification : Notification) {
    print(notification)
}
```

You have to filter the notifications related to Time Machine. You can also observe specific notifications via the `name` parameter

Comment: How do I determine the notification names to listen to? I set up listeners for all strings in `backupd` and `backupd-helper` and only got two distinct notifications (`com.apple.TimeMachine.UICleanupNeeded`, `WillDeleteLocalSnapshot`). It's no longer possible to listen to all notifications. 
https://twitter.com/BrianHenryIE/status/1716214642668966277