# Notification when TimeMachine backup starts/ends

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, notificationcenter, timemachine

I want to get notified in my Swift Cocoa Application (not sandboxed) when a TimeMachine starts or ends.
So far I tried to listen for every Notification coming in the DistributedNotificationCenter by setting the `name:` parameter to *nil* as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54927655/event-notifications-in-macos).

But it seems like passing in nil as an argument is not supported anymore (I am currently on macOS Monterey) because I do not get a single notification at all.

This is the code I tried:

```
DistributedNotificationCenter.default().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(test(_:)), name: nil, object: nil)

@objc func test(_ aNotification: Notification) {
     print(aNotification)
}
```

I tried to find a specific notification name for TimeMachine but found nothing.